# Prove true or false with counter example $\lVert\vec{u}\rVert=\lVert\vec{v}\rVert \implies (\vec{u}+\vec{v}) \cdot (\vec{u}-\vec{v})=0 $

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, normed-spaces, inner-products

### Problem

Prove true or false with counter example  $$\lVert\vec{u}\rVert=\lVert\vec{v}\rVert \implies (\vec{u}+\vec{v}) \cdot (\vec{u}-\vec{v})=0 $$

when $\{\vec{u},\vec{v}\}\in \mathbb{R}^n$

### Attempt to solve

Let $\{\vec{u},\vec{v}\}\in \mathbb{R}^2$ then i can display $
\vec{u},\vec{v}$ as:

$$ \vec{u}=\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix}, \vec{v}= \begin{bmatrix} 
b \\ a \end{bmatrix} $$

$\lVert\vec{u}\rVert=\lVert\vec{v}\rVert$ can be only true when both vectors have same elements when order doesn't matter.

where $\{a,b\}\in \mathbb{R}$

$$ \sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\sqrt{b^2+a^2} \implies \begin{bmatrix} a + b \\ b + a \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} a - b \\ b - a \end{bmatrix}=0 $$

$$ \implies (a+b)\cdot (a-b) + (b+a) \cdot (b-a) $$
$$ = a\cdot a + a \cdot (-b) + b \cdot a + b \cdot (-b)+ b \cdot b + b \cdot (-a) + a \cdot b + a \cdot (-a)$$

$$ = a^2-a^2+ab-ab+ab-ab+b^2-b^2 = 0 $$

which is true when $ \{\vec{u},\vec{v}\} \in \mathbb{R}^2 $ but not in $\mathbb{R}^n$. How do  you prove this for $\mathbb{R}^n$ case ?

Comment: In order to reuse what you have done, you could prove it by induction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{align}(\vec u+\vec v).(\vec u-\vec v)&=\vec u.\vec u-\vec u.\vec v+\vec v.\vec u-\vec v.\vec v\\&=\|\vec u\|^2-\|\vec v\|^2\\&=0\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\|u\|^2 & =\|v\|^2\\
u \cdot u & =v \cdot v\\
(u \cdot u)+(u \cdot v)-(u \cdot v)-(v \cdot v)&=0\\
(u+v) \cdot (u-v)& =0.
\end{align*}